# Ubuntu 14.04 freezes on an Asus G75v laptop

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia, freeze

I've installed the latest Ubuntu on my father's laptop (v. 14.04.3). After convincing him that it was better than Windows, he started to work on it an he liked it.

But shortly after using it, an issue arised: **The computer freezes and he has to reset it manually. It doesn't matter what program he's using it, or if he's opening something or just reading from the screen, after a while it just freezes.**

Sometimes the mouse won't work, and sometimes you can move the mouse over the screen, but you can't click anything. (I can't even open the terminal to shut the machine down).

I've run `inxi -G` and `xrandr` in order to get some information. His laptop is an **Asus G75v Intel core i7, with nVidia Geforce GTX 660M 2gb**.

I assume it has something to do with the nVidia drivers? What should I do?

(Please note that I've run `apt-get` in order to update Ubuntu, but it didn't do any difference. I also read [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/423503/ubuntu-12-04-and-13-10-freeze-and-white-screen-with-nvidia-gtx-660?rq=1), but as it is an older Ubuntu version, I don't think this is a duplicate post).

[image]

Comment: I've tried to install the nVidia Drivers [read this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/451221/ubuntu-14-04-install-nvidia-driver). Theer are lots of recommendations, I've followed this: 

`sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa` and then `sudo apt-get update`, and then I've installed **nvidia-current** package.

After that I did `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall` and rebooted the machine. 

Can't tell if it worked after a couple of days, but I wanted to report on what I've done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the currently installed NVIDIA drivers and the xorg-edgers PPA.

Open a terminal and execute :

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
sudo ppa-purge ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
sudo reboot
```

Install the latest stable NVIDIA drivers that support GEFORCE GTX 660M.

Open a terminal and execute :

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-352 nvidia-prime
sudo reboot
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Anyway, I've posted what I've done as a comment of my own question, and after a month, I can report that the problem is gone with that. Just in case anyone wonders.  :)